# I'm trying to figure out what the symbol on my main screen on my s3 means

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I was wondering what the symbol on my top screen of my phone was it kinda looks like a sun with a smaller sun in it and it just spins and pops on an off

Comment: Can you take a screenshot? I haven't seen anything like that on any Samsung devices that I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Is it possible it is the location info icon? See the fifth from the bottom on this [image](http://i1.wp.com/newsandguides.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Nokia-Lumia-820-User-Guide-Icons-shown-on-your-phone-Nokia-USA.png?resize=483%2C566). Don't know if it blinks.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a GPS icon from what you've described. You can check the official [list](http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00057016/73914/SM-N900TZKETMB) of icons for a Samsung device to be sure.